# Constructor result type is not <:< class type on class with type parameter

Tags: scala, reflection

According to `<:<`, the result type of a class's constructor is not that of the class, if the class has a type parameter. Here's a small program to demonstrate:

```
// Scala 2.11.1
case class ClassWithTypeParam[A](x: Int)

def main(args: Array[String]) {
  val classType = weakTypeOf[ClassWithTypeParam[String]]
  val constructorType = classType.decl(termNames.CONSTRUCTOR).asMethod.typeSignature
  val MethodType(constructorParams, resultType) = constructorType
  println(s"$classType\n$constructorType\n$constructorParams\n$resultType\n")
  println(resultType <:< classType)  // should print "true"
}
```

Here's the output:

```
ClassWithTypeParam[String]
(x: scala.Int)ClassWithTypeParam[A]
List(value x)
ClassWithTypeParam[A]

false
```

It also fails if I call `typeOf` rather than `weakTypeOf`. The last line is `true` when I try this on classes that don't have type parameters.

Do I need to call `.substituteTypes` or `.typeSignatureIn`? If so, what belongs in the arguments to these methods? I haven't found much documentation on them.

Comment: `false` looks correct to me. `resultType <:< classType` is only true if `A` is `String`, which cannot be guaranteed.

Comment: That might be the key clue. I got the constructor from `ClassWithTypeParam[String]` and expected the constructor to return that type. Evidently it doesn't. So how do I get the constructor specifically for `ClassWithTypeParam[String]`?

Comment: decl(...).typeSignatureIn(classType)

Comment: @EugeneBurmako Well, that works! Thanks. If you'd like +15 glory, just post it as an answer. Could you briefly explain what is the full meaning of "site" as this word is used in the documentation for `typeSignatureIn`?

Comment: I think it refers to the precise type of the owner. Site probably means the definition site for the symbol one's getting the signature for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use typeSignatureIn instead of just typeSignature in order to get type information that accounts for the precise type of the owner of the symbol.